# How to Convert PromQL to KQL

Tags: prometheus, azure-data-explorer, kql, promql

I was wondering if anyone knows tool or workaround for converting Prometheus query to Kusto query?
Also any Microsoft tool which graph Prometheus data can be helpful as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of translation tool from PromoQL to Kusto Query Language. As for the Prometheus data, check out this article about [sending Prometheus to Kusto](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/prometheusio-azure-data-explorer-henning-rauch/) (Azure Data Explorer)